# How to Use the Same Bamboo Deployment Project Structure for Different Deployments without Cloning

Tags: bamboo

I would like to be able to use a single deployment project that can be initiated with different configurations (presumably with different variables) for different deployment needs. I don't want to take the baseline deployment project, clone it, and then use different variables for each cloned project. The problem with that is that if the structure changes, you have to maintain multiple cloned projects.

Here is a use case example I would like to be able to do:

deploymentA -> use baseline deployment project with deploymentA configuration.

deploymentB -> use baseline deployment project with deploymentB configuration.

deploymentC -> use baseline deployment project with deploymentC configuration.

etc. Any ideas are appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like the "[Conditional tasks for Bamboo](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1219706/conditional-tasks-for-bamboo?hosting=server&tab=overview)" Plugin that Atlassian Labs provides.  This will allow you to trigger the same build pipeline and conditionally execute tasks.